# Set Pikachoose to show ONLY thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to modify [pikachoose](http://www.pikachoose.com/) to show only thumbnails.  I have already modified the code a litle and this is what I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/deQdG.png

This is what i have modified in base.css

```
/* Style the thumbnails */
.pika-thumbs {
    padding: 0 16px;
    height: 75px;
}

.pika-thumbs li {
    width: 144px;
    height: 74px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 17px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pika-thumbs li .clip {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*for the tool tips*/
.pika-tooltip {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.pika-counter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 45px;
    left: 15px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* If using user thumbnails there's a pause while the new large image loads. This is the loader for that */      
.pika-loader {
    background: url(loading.gif) 3px 3px no-repeat #000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    color: white;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

What I must modify in [jquery.pikachoose.js](http://www.pikachoose.com/) to do this?

The site I'm working on is http://brassds.com/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to http://brassds.com/servicios.html, the documentation for [Pikachoose](http://www.pikachoose.com/versions/) states:

> PikaChoose will create thumbnails for you, but if you want to use your
>   own it’s easy. You set the src for your images to your thumbnail
>   image. Then you’ll add a ref attribute (not rel!) with the full size
>   image like the example below. PikaChoose will pull in the full size
>   image automatically.

```
<img src="thumbnail.jpg" ref="fullsize.jpg" >
```

Further assuming that `Servicios-pequena1.jpg` points to the thumbnail and `Servicos-1.jpg` is the full-size image, you should be able to modify your source to look like this:

```
<ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/trabajos/Servicios-pequena1.jpg" ref="images/trabajos/Servicos-1.jpg" alt=""/></a><span></span></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/trabajos/Servicios-pequena2.jpg" ref="images/trabajos/Servicos-2.jpg" alt=""/></a><span></span></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/trabajos/Servicios-pequena3.jpg" ref="images/trabajos/Servicos-3.jpg" alt=""/></a><span></span></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and [Pikachoose](http://www.pikachoose.com/versions/) should set up the thumbnails for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i want to put a new pikachoose in the index.html I have modified and included all i need. Like the image what i want to do is eliminate the slide and only keep the thumbnails like a gallery

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
.pika-stage {
    display: none;
}
```

Add it to your stylesheet for your PikaChoose gallery and make sure it loads before the pikachoose() function launches.

The .pika-stage element is auto-created by the PikaChoose class so, while you could probably remove it this is just way easier.

Also, you might want to call pikachoose() with the carousel to give a little flair...

```
$("#id").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
```